# Move Image in Div with Readjusting Editable Text

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to be able to move an image and type in a div on the same screen, and have the text wrap around the image as it is being moved.  So far I've been able to do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uk6DA/

But when the image is moved, the text does not change its position.  How might the text get readjusted as the image is moved?

Comment: How are you wanting the text to change?  do you want it to surround the DIV when you move it?  Or did you want it to take up the space that the DIV was occupying before?  Or a mixture of the two?

Comment: I'd like the text in the DIV to surround the image as it is being moved.  Of course if it does that, it will take up the space where the image was before at the same time.  So I guess it's a mixture.

Comment: is that what you are asking for? 

http://www.meindesign.net/tools/running_text.php

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: That is a great demo, and great coding, but after looking at it more, I noticed every word is put into its own span tag.  Makes editing nearly impossible.  Reduces the integrity of the text, makes formatting like Bold and Italic more difficult. so I'm not sure if I would want to take that approach.  Still looks great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this all has to do with placement within the DOM.

If you're serious about doing something like this, I think you're going to have to find where the element sits when you move it, then change its place in the DOM based on that.  You'll probably want to put the text in an element too.

So, in the beginning, `#typer` preceeds the text.  But when you move it, you're going to have to do a couple of things.  You'll have to see where the left and top edges of `#typer` sit, and what text they sit on top of.  Then, you'll have to make calculations to modify them within the DOM from there.

I'm guessing you'll either have to add a bunch of `span`'s or `div`'s to the text, to be able to recreate the text appropriately, to fit around the element.  This would get a bit difficult too, because the lengths aren't fixed, they're dynamic.  With the text inside a `div` or `span`, you won't get the "wrap-around" to the side of the page, it will just fall down to the next line within that element.

## Initial Setup

[image]

## After Movement

[image]

That should explain how you're going to have to split them up.  It may get pretty complicated, but you can do it.  You'll just have to mess with different types of measurements.  I've done things very similar to this in the past.

Basically, just keep track of where you split the text (that's why they have the IDs in sequential order), so you can join them.  Measure how much space the text takes up, how much space the image takes up, and how large the canvas area you can work with is.

From there, you should have a pretty good gauge of what to do.  Just make sure that your text doesn't break to the next line if it overflows.  If that happens, it'll break and ruin the illusion.

So, as far as placement in the DOM goes:

## Initial Setup

```
<div id="typer">
    <img id="img" />
    <div class="text"> ..... </div>
</div>
```

## After Movement

```
<div id="typer">
    <div class="text" id="text1"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text2"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text4"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text6"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text8"> ... </div>
    <img id="img" />
    <div class="text" id="text3"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text5"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text7"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text9"> ... </div>
    <div class="text" id="text10"> ... </div>
</div>
```

That's going to be the "easiest" route to set it up for the CSS too, unless you `position: absolute;` everything, which can work too.

Comment: Ok, that definitely explains it.  So my idea of fluid wraparound movement cannot be done, at least not easily.  I think you're right.  I'll just keep this post up a little longer, and if nobody has any solutions I'll accept your explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Words don't have coordinates, so you have to wrap each word with a html-tag. And obviously this will increase the text a lot.

http://meindesign.net/tools/running_text.php

this is the best example of what you need.

And I dont know how this works..but you may want to look at this too

http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/

Best of luck.

Comment: The first example would would make text editing pretty difficult. The second example looks like it might work with editable text though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working the "resized" img div along with the text inside of it?

You could float: left; the img and right the text. place a min-width to avoid getting it too small.